# res://ieframe.dll/acr-err loading my applet in IE 11 //windows 8/8.1// on java 6?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, applet

I have a bug running with windows 8/8.1 while loading my applet.

I googled acr-err and i found that is related to compatibility view in IE 11.
Changing it with developer tools works fine , I tried to add meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
```

but that only works when I put it in the head tag. That is the perfect solution because my applet works fine with other java version in  IE11.

I tried also

```
$document.prepend('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>');
```

in bloc  if that detecting java version.

It is added but the document mode by default in IE11 not changing .. so my applet won't work ... 
help please

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the document mode with javascript, because it can only set once, while loading the DOM.

If it works with the meta-tag in the head section, use it.

It will also work, if your server delivers an HTP-header "X-UA-Compatible" with that value.

There is an "enterprise compatibility mode" for the IE11, where you can specify the urls, which should be displayed with compat mode.

The last option is to enable "compat mot for all intranet sites", and put the url into the intranet-site zone.

Well... IE and compat mode is fun.

You should also consider to replace the applet with never technologies, because most browser will remove plugins or already have them removed.

Comment: Reqrite the complete code to maybe Java-Webstart.

I think (just an opinion), no mayor browser will support plugins in 2016. (The IE will be the only browser, which will execute plugins)